# How to connect database and joomla website on cpanel

Tags: joomla, web-hosting, cpanel, joomla1.7

There is a joomla 1.7 website I want to host.I have uploaded the database and the joomla folder to the cpanel.How can i do to connect the database and the joomla folder so that they can be accessed by the public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add db details like Host name, user name , password, log path, tmp path accordingly in **configuration.php** in the joomla root folder.